# Set Alarm in Alexa device with text input using AVS

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

We need to set alarm programmatically i.e. We will send request dynamically by text to AVS for setting Alarm.
I can not find any specific link which can help me with this.
In All examples,I have referred,Request for Event of setting alarm is being sent by voice.
Is it possible to send the event request by text ?

Any help will be highly appreciable.
Please guide me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the GitHub project

> https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid

In this project, we can use voice and text inputs. While using Text, the text we entered is converted to voice through TextToSpeech Engine and send to AVS and get the output from AVS.